# Prepositional phrase modify

Tags: prepositional-phrases, dangling-modifier

> Habituation is the decline in response to a specific stimulus over time, when that stimulus is repeatedly presented to the organism.

The prepositional phrase **in response** is adjective and modifies **the decline**,
**to a specific stimulus** is also an adjective prepositional phrase, and does it modifies **response**?

By the way, If the prepositional phrase is acting like an adjective , can it only modify the thing in front of it or can it modify something far from it?

Like the example above,
assuming that  "**to a specific stimulus** semantically modifies **response**"    isn't wrong,
grammatically, can **to a specific stimulus** modify **the decline**?

Comment: No; the PP "in decline" can hardly be an adjective can it! Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective. In any case, the PP "In response" does not modify "decline", but is a complement of it. The PP " to a specific stimulus ..." is complement of "response".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everything that affects, modifies or refines a noun is an adjective, as BillJ mentions in the comments. Some nouns can take arguments, as a verb does, and these can be called *complements*. It's not that they are *changing* the meaning of the noun, as an adjective does, but they are *completing* it (hence 'complement').

*Decline*, on its own, raises the question "decline in **what**?". In this case, that question is answered with "response to a specific stimulus". Likewise, *response* prompts the question "response to what?" - and that question is answered with "a specific stimulus". *Specific*, on the other hand, is simply an adjective modifying *stimulus*. Thus, *stimulus* is a noun modified with an adjective to form the noun phrase *specific stimulus*. *Response* is a noun, completed by the noun phrase *a specific stimulus* (linked with *to*), and *decline* is a noun, completed by the noun phrase *response to a specific stimulus* (linked with *in*).

> Habituation is the [decline [in [response [to [a specific stimulus]]] [over time]]

Comment: Thank you , this is the site I visited when learning PP phrase (https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/prepositional_phrase.htm), it didn't mention anything about complement when introducing the function of PP phrases. Do you recommend this website and is there a better website for english learner for learning PP phrase?

Comment: @jessie: I'm afraid that I don't know much about sites for learners, being a native speaker, but there's a brief explanation of complements of nouns here: https://www.englishgrammar.org/complements-verbs-nouns-adjectives/

Comment: Thank you, i will study the provided site :) By the way , can I bother with one more question. Can one argue that "a specific stimulus" can be a complement of "decline"(linked by "to") , but semantically wouldn't make much sense?

Comment: @Jessie: complements will generally be closest to the noun they are complementing, it's tight binding. If there weren't another noun in between, and you just had "decline to a specific stimulus", then you *could* parse it as a complement and it wouldn't be semantically valid. It would be more likely that people would parse it as *decline* being a verb, as *decline to* is usually a catenative use of *to decline*, but then that would fail to make sense (or parse properly) either. It would just confuse people.

Comment: Thanks again, cause when I was approaching the sentence, I was using a more simple sentence to help me understand the structure, but seems like it's quite different.EX: "The boy with a bag in the room is reading" , in this case,  both "with a bag" and "in the room" will be the complement of **the boy**, is this correct?

Comment: @jessie That one is semantically ambiguous, because "in the room" could apply to the bag or the boy. Given that, I would tend to read it as applying to "the bag" rather than the boy. Also, those are adjectivals, not complements; they describe the things, rather than completing their meaning.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am getting a better understanding of it :)

Answer (score 0):

> *Habituation is the decline* [*in response* [*to a specific stimulus over*
>   *time*]], *when that stimulus is repeatedly presented to the organism.*

The PPs are not modifiers, but **complements**.

The outer brackets surround a PP serving as complement of "decline". Within that PP,
 the inner brackets surround a further PP serving as complement of "response".

Thus, we have one PP functioning within the structure of another.